# Atrapado con una funcion en JS

Tags: javascript, funciones

Estoy terminando un ejercicio con JS (Mars Rover Kata). 
Consiste en hacer un objeto movil (rover) el cual se ira moviendo a traves de una cuadricula de 10x10.

No es complicado pero me tiene atrapado la ultima parte de este. Tengo que aNadir otro rover y hacer que se turnen para moverse, hasta ahi bien. El problema llega cuando quiero que cada rover acepte ordenes distintas, p. ejemplo:

Rover 1, gira derecha, avanza, avanza.

Rover 2, gira izquierda, avanza, avanza.

No tengo cojones a poner bien la funcion para que me admita un comando para cada rover.

Dejo por aqui la funcion en cuestion y el enunciado del ejercicio a ver si alguien con mas conocimiento o un enfoque diferente puede echarme una mano a resolver el problema.

> Other Rovers - Add additional rovers to the map. Have them take turns
>   moving. If one rover is going to run into the other, you should stop
>   the rover and console.log a message saying so.

```
function command(commandLine, rover) {
    for (let b = 0; b < rover.length; b++){
      for (let i = 0; i < commandLine.length; i++) {
        switch (commandLine[i]) {
            case 'l': turnLeft(rover[b]); break;
            case 'r': turnRight(rover[b]); break;
            case 'f': moveForward(rover[b]);
                rover[b].travelLog.push(`x=${rover[b].x}  y=${rover[b].y}`);
                break;
            case 'b': moveBackward(rover[b]);
                rover[b].travelLog.push(`x=${rover[b].x}  y=${rover[b].y}`);
                break;
            default: console.log(`Sir, the command ${i} is not valid. Please, check the Command List. `);
                break;
        }
      } 
      console.log(`${rover[b].name} Travel Log: ${rover[b].travelLog}`);
      grid[rover[b].y][rover[b].x] = 'R'
      console.log(grid.join('\n'));
    }
}
```

Si hace falta alguna aclaracion o mas codigo para comprenderlo mejor, ya me decis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese doble bucle está haciendo que para cada rover, ejecutes todas las instrucciones, pero creo que lo que quieres es ejecutar una instrucción, pasar al siguiente rover, ejecutar otra instrucción... y volver al primer rover cuando los has recorrido todos, hasta que no queden instrucciones. Además puedes ahorrarte el switch así:

```
let movementFns= {
  l: turnLeft,
  r: turnRight,
  b: rover => {
    moveBackward(rover);
    rover.travelLog.push(`x=${rover.x}  y=${rover.y}`);
  },
  f: rover => {
    moveForward(rover);
    rover.travelLog.push(`x=${rover.x}  y=${rover.y}`);
  }
}

function command(commandLine, rovers) {
  commandLine.forEach(command => {
    let rover = rovers.shift(); //sacamos el primero
    let func = movementFns[command];
    if (func) {
      func(rover);
    } else {
      console.log(`Sir, the command ${command} is not valid. Please, check the Command List. `);
    }
    rovers.push(rover); //lo colocamos el último
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola Pablo! Gracias por la ayuda. Finalmente lo solucione aNadiendo let n = 0; y un switch case 2: n = 1;
De esta manera cuando escribo en CommandList el 2 (p.ejemplo: rff2lff), pasa automaticamente al Rover two.

De todas formas me quedo con el ejemplo de tu codigo para hacer algo mas limpio en el futuro. Gracias!